# VBA Célula Mesclada

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde,

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como retornar o valor de uma célula mesclada na programação VBA ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo: Gostaria que o range N6 retornasse MAI/19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obter o valor diretamente, normalmente é utilizado o valor da célula mais à esquerda e superior. Mas há uma maneira melhor de obter, como pode ser visto no código a seguir:

```
Sub valor_mesclado()
    MsgBox Range("H6").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
    MsgBox Range("E6").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Pelo fato de a célula estar mesclada o VBA ele utiliza como parâmetro a primeira celula que foi mesclada, logo o valor MAI/2019  está na celula E6.